# Access Session data using caching API

Tags: c#, .net, appfabric

I am new to AppFabric. I configured my application to use AppFabric for session management. But I am not able to read the session data using caching API.

I used the following logic to read.

```
Session['Name'] = 'x';
public static DataCacheFactory cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory();
private DataCache cache = cacheFactory.GetCache("EmpCache");
cache.Get("Name", out version);
```

Is it expected?

Answer (score 1):

If you've set up AppFabric as your [session state provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361711%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), there's no need to query the cache yourself; you should treat the session state cache as a totally separate black box. So for your example, the code should be:

```
Session["Name"] = "x";
// AppFabric stores the session state somewhere

// A short time (and possibly a postback) later
string name = Session["Name"]);
// The provider takes care of retrieving the value from the AppFabric cache
```

(By comparison, if you were storing session state using the In-Process provider, you wouldn't start trying to query the internals of the provider in memory this way; treat the AppFabric provider in the same manner)

Comment: I know that I can read by Session["Name"], but I am exploring internals of AppFabric to write a custom provider instead of using default provider. Can anyone please answer if it is possible to do something like this? I am fine to use any existing modules for the same purpose